# How to create a type alias for a function type in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013

Using VS2013, I can create a typedef to a function type like so:

```
typedef void ResponseCallback(std::string const&);
```

Is it possible to use type aliasing (I have access to C++11 features) to do the same? I've been trying to migrate away from using `typedef` as `using` seems to be more consistent going forward. I've tried something like below but it does not work:

```
using ResponseCallback = void (std::string const&);
```

I get a vaguely unhelpful error message from Visual Studio 2013 as follows:

> error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'string'

Comment: *"it does not work"* Looks fine to me. Also, clang++ accepts it: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cd4f7dc32163ae4a What exactly "does not work"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can however wrap it.

```
template < typename P1 >
using ResponseCallback = 
typename std::remove_pointer < void (*)( P1 const & ) >::type;
```

I tested it on VS2013 and heres the [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9001b4a3e5f786d8)

Or a simple bogus wrapper like this will satisfy VS2013 too:

```
template < typename functype >
struct functype_wrapper
{
    typedef functype type;
};

//using ResponseCallback = void ( std::string const & ); // nope
using ResponseCallback = functype_wrapper < void ( std::string const & ) >::type; // oke
```

Answer (score 0):

Various comments to my question verified I am using the alias correctly, which lead me to believe this might be a tooling problem. I tested the same alias on Clang and GCC and it worked just fine. So this must just be another unsupported/poorly implemented C++11 feature in Visual Studio 2013.

I do however recommend @Slyps excellent answer for applicable workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have `-std=c++11` available, you may want to use the newer convention for this type of functionality.

```
#include <functional>

typedef std::function<void(std::string const &)> ResponseCallback;
```

This would allow you to do what you're trying to do, as well as utilize lambdas, functors, or function pointers.